# How do I retrieve lost changes in a git repo?

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I work at a small studio which is new to using Git, so we have no Git masters here. Recently, a developer managed to, in the process of pushing a small change, completely remove a bunch of other changes from the codebase.

It looks like when he merged, he merged with some old revision, one which was missing added files, and had old versions of files. So when he pushed his commit up to the server, the end result is deleted files, and files whose contents are now missing many changes.

Now, if you clone a new depot, all the code in the main branch is missing all the circled changes in the below image. The commits for those changes are still in the log, only the changes they represented are not in the code.

Basically, the problem can be seen in this image:

[image: The problems]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to [`git revert`](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html) the merge commit and make the developer redo the merge, correctly this time.

`git revert <sha>` will record a new commit that undoes the effects of `<sha>`, which should be your bad merge commit.

Since this change has been pushed to the central repository already, you shouldn't use any of git's rewrite-history magic.

Comment: How exactly do I use git revert to do this? Nothing I try seems to work properly. I can't figure out how to undo the bad merge, basically.

Comment: I don't understand what's not clear. Type `git revert 9a9b6b` at a command prompt, and it will create a new commit that undoes all of the changes in the bad merge commit `9a9b6b`

Comment: Not exactly -- git revert requires the -m flag since it's a merge that's being reverted. Through trial and error I figured out which parent gave me the revert I wanted, though I'm still fuzzy on what picking the parent means in the context of reverting a merge.

Answer (score 2):

Couple days ago I ran into same situation.

**Possible cause**

I've found out that possible cause for such merges could be someone using

```
git merge -s ours <somebranch>
```

without even knowing that.

Some developers don't use console and pull/commit/push using their IDEs. When something goes bad, some IDEs present options like "force", "resolve to mine", etc... which are not always should be clicked unless one exactly knows what it does.

Bad thing is that after such a merge commit pushed git will tell you that all the commits of merged branch are in there, however you won't find any of those changes.... Sad story.

**Solution to go**

We decided to go with the resetting master back to the latest point when everything was OK.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard
git reset --hard <OKAY_POINT>
```

In your case `<OKAY_POINT>` is `3221961`.

And then we had to forcefully push this to the upstream.

```
git push --force
```

As a result `origin/master` was reset to the state before that bad merge happened.

Generally it is NOT a good idea. But we went with it since all the team is local, most guys were aware of what's happening and no-one committed anything on top of that broken master at the moment forced back reset was happening.

Afterwards the developer who broke the master had to redo his merge and this time the right way.

The only other option without resetting remote I see is to manually re-merge everything that commit might have "erased". Which does not seem like something simple to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but you can almost always use [`git reflog`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-reflog) to get back something that was accidently removed

Comment: I can't tell from the description of that command what exactly it is supposed to be able to do for me.

Comment: Using reflog doesn't seem to be necessary here. The commits are still in the branch, it's just that their changes are not reflected in the head commit of the branch.

Comment: Looks like you are correct svick, the question was edited after my post to better describe the problem.